# Getting Xcode4 and using iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with it

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have currently installed version of xcode is 3 and iPhone SDK which I am using is 3.1.3. Now what I want is that I just want the Xcode 4 not iOS 4 sdk. That means I just want to upgrade my Xcode to Xcode 4. How to do that and I am offline. So how to upgrade if I do not have internet on my Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use iOS 4 SDK you can still compile for 3.1.3 - set the "iOS Deployment Target" in the "Info" of the Targets and the project to 3.1.3.

If you want to upgrade to XCode 4, you have to be a registered developer (it's still in beta, so it's not available to anyone else until final release) and transfer it via a USB stick, CD etc.  It's not available through the usual Mac Software Update.

Comment: i downloaded the xcode4 it came with ios sdk. when i installed it it wiped out my old sdks 3.1, 3.1.3 and 3.2 I thought that it will just upgrade my xcode and will install ios sdk, but it didnt happen that way......